# How to convert date format and add hh:mm:ss to it

Tags: python, date, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

My issue is that user can input any date format, `12-feb-2015` or `12/10/2015`, i need to convert this in below format :

```
12-feb-2015 00:00:00
```

this further would be fed in a MySQL query which would then be used to fetch data in given date ranges
so i have 2 questions :

- is there any standard way to convert *any* input format to my required one?
- how can i append `hh:mm:ss` to it?

i saw lot of methods on SO thread but none seem to help me out.

Comment: Is it **any** date format or just the two you listed?

Comment: @AlG : at present it can be *any* but i'll limit it to these 2.Issue is that i need to have user friendly *month - Feb / Mar / Apr* included as its mandatory, other one is optional (*but can't be removed*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally SO isn't a code writing service but... :)

This is only a start to what you could do. I'm unaware of any way to have one test catch multiple formats. Instead I've always "gone through" the available formats. Since we're talking about two, here's something to kick-start your thinking:

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_date(thedate):
    result = None

    #try each format
    try:
        result = datetime.strptime(thedate, "%d-%b-%Y")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    except:
        raise

    # Let the last one "blow" up
    if result is None:
        result = datetime.strptime(thedate, "%d/%m/%Y")

    print "{} parsed into {}".format(thedate,result.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

`parse_date("12/10/2015")` yields `12/10/2015 parsed into 12-Oct-2015 00:00:00`
and 
`parse_date("12-feb-2015")` yields `12-feb-2015 parsed into 12-Feb-2015 00:00:00`

That should get you going. Check out the [strptime/strftime formats here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) (scroll down to the strftime function).

Comment: *Normally SO isn't a code writing service but... :)* - i know it pretty well fella, i was looking for an approach or indication in right direction, not *code writing service* ...anyway, minor tweaking and your solution was helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your approach is that *any* kind of format may be infinite kinds how much you can imagine.

Inspired in @al-g's answer, I propose an approach using a set of known data formats.

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(dtm):
    formats = ['%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S']
    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(dtm, fmt).strftime('%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except:
            raise
    print 'Format not recognized'

>>> convert('15072015')
Format not recognized
>>> convert('15-07-2015')
'15/Jul/2015 00:00:00'
>>> convert('15/07/2015')
'15/Jul/2015 00:00:00'
```

You can update the set of formats every time you find new one.